# How to retrieve the value from LocalStorage

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to test out html5 localStorage feature. For some reason, whenever I try to retrieve a value from storage after refreshing the page, i dont get any value. Values are getting stored locally on my click functionality. But when i refresh the page, it doesnt show the values.

**src/app.component.ts File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class MyItems {
  value: string;
  constructor(value:string){
    this.value = value;
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = "Working with Angular";
  myItems: MyItems[] = new Array();
  IsForUpdate: boolean = false;
  newItem: any = {};
  updatedItem;

  constructor(){
    this.myItems.push(    
      new MyItems("First Value"),    
      new MyItems("Second Value"),    
      new MyItems("Third Value"),    
      new MyItems("Forth Value"),    
      new MyItems("Fifth Value")    
    );
    localStorage.setItem("Values", JSON.stringify(MyItems));
    var getValues = localStorage.getItem("Values");        
  }
      
  AddItem() {    
    this.myItems.push(    
      this.newItem    
    );    
    this.newItem = {};
    localStorage.setItem('dataSource', this.newItem);
    localStorage.getItem('dataSource');    
    // console.log(localStorage.getItem('dataSource'));
  }  
 

  EditItems(i){
    this.newItem.value = this.myItems[i].value;
    this.updatedItem = i;
    this.IsForUpdate = true;
  }



  UpdateItem(){
    let data = this.updatedItem;
    for(let i=0; i < this.myItems.length; i++){
      if(i == data){
        this.myItems[i].value = this.newItem.value;
      }
    }
    this.IsForUpdate = false;
    this.newItem = {};
  }

 
  DeleteItem(i) {
    var confirmMe = confirm('Do you want to Delete it ?');
    if(confirmMe == true){
      this.myItems.splice(i, 1); 
    } else {
      alert("You cancelled the Operation");
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Which local storage key are you having an issue with, `Values` or `dataSource` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to store arrays or objects in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you will need to convert it into a string format, as localStorage only supports the storing of string values. You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for that purpose.

```
localStorage.setItem('Values', JSON.stringify(this.newItem));

localStorage.setItem('dataSource', JSON.stringify(this.items));
```

Likewise, when you need to retrieve the item from localStorage, you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it back into an array or object.

```
const storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataSource'));
```

---

On your constructor, you are overcomplicating the way you populate your array. After populating the myItems array, you can store it in your localStorage.

On your `addItem()` method, you can simply push the new items to your myItems array, and call `localStorage.setItem()`, which will overwrite the previous value stored on your `Values` key.

```
myItems: string[] = [];

constructor(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Values')));

  this.myItems.push('First Value', 'First Value', 'Third Value', 'Forth Value', 'Fifth Value');
  localStorage.setItem('Values', JSON.stringify(this.myItems));
}

addItem() {
  const newItem = ''; //replace that with any value you desire
  this.myItems.push(newItem)
  localStorage.setItem('Values', JSON.stringify(this.myItems));
}
```

Comment: But how can i retrieve the items after addition in my code ? Can you pls help me in that

Comment: @tkamath99 Are you referring to the code within your `AddItem()` method? Alright, what exactly do you want to retrieve?

Comment: In the constructor i am adding the content in an array which displays in the frontpage within a box. So whenever i add a new item from AddItem() i want it to stay there even after page refresh

Comment: Alright, and this.myItems contains this, right? `['First Value', 'Second Value', ...]`

Comment: @tkamath99 yeah, I see. Alright, have you seen my the second part of my answer?

Comment: Yes i tried it, but it is giving an error as 'Argument of type '"'' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Myitems'

Comment: @tkamath99 is myItems an array of strings? Or can it contain other primitive data types such as numbers?

Comment: It is just an array of strings

Comment: If it is an array of strings, change your typecast and typecast it as `myItems: string[] = [];`

Comment: Its done. I didnt typecast it to string. But rather i removed the push method from constructor. I  compared it whether the localstorage was null and used getItem method to display the values from localstorage. Actually the array method in constructor was making all the chaos.