# localstorage value set in one component gives null in other component angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, local-storage, behaviorsubject

I have angular application which has header, user section, timeline components. In header, I have log in form. After log in user redirected to timeline component which calls user section component. In header component I need to  store user data in localstorage after log in. And that data I need to access in user section.

**Header component**: on successfull login  `getUserDetails()` is called

```
 getUserDetails() {
 this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data["status"] === false) {
      } else {
        this.loadingFlag = true;
        this.selecteduser = data["data"];
        localStorage.setItem(
        "selecteduser",
           JSON.stringify(data["data"])
         );
     }
 });
}
```

**user-section component**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
 console.log('user sec', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'))); // Gives null after 
                                                                            //log in
}
```

I tried to get data using `BehaviorSubject` also in multiple ways but didn't worked e.g. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512030/javascript-localstorage-not-available-in-another-component-unless-i-refresh-the). It shows null every time. Its like getting value as soon as it is set as after log in redirected to component which tries to get set data.

How can I get localstorage data in user-section component which is set in header component?

I tried to explain but sorry if I confuse while explaining my problem.

Please guide and help. Thanks.

**Edit:**

In user section I need to access that localstorage data on condition.

```
            ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getUserDetails();
            }
            
            getUserDetails() {
                if (this.user_id == null) {
              console.log('user sec', 
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser')));
this.selecteduser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'));
     this.fullName =
                this.selecteduser.first_name + ' ' + this.selecteduser.last_name;
                this.userVerified = this.selecteduser.verified;
            }
            else if(this.user_id == this.id)
            {
this.selecteduser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'));
     this.fullName =
                this.selecteduser.first_name + ' ' + this.selecteduser.last_name;
                this.userVerified = this.selecteduser.verified;
             }
            else{
            // other api call
            }
        
        }
```

**Edit 2:**
**First login**

[image]

**Then logout and login 2nd time**

[image]

**Then logout and login 3nd time**

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that data is being set in `localStorage` by checking in the `application` tab of chrome dev tools?

Comment: @HassanMoin yes it sets

Comment: It is too hard to answer without all code. Did you run TS Lint? No issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a getter/setter in your user service which returns/sets a `ReplaySubject`, add the value in that `ReplaySubject` when you get the response from the userService method `this.userService.getUserDetails`. And then in your `user-section` subscribe to your getter from the userService to get the details only when the user data is set in the localStorage.

User Service

```js
selectedUserInLocal$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject();

setSelectedUserFlag(temp: boolean): void{
   this.selectedUserInLocal$.next(temp);
} 
getSelectedUserFlag(): ReplaySubject<boolean> {
   return this.selectedUserInLocal$;
}
```

```js
getUserDetails() {
 this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data["status"] === false) {
      } else {
        this.loadingFlag = true;
        this.selecteduser = data["data"];
        localStorage.setItem(
        "selecteduser",
           JSON.stringify(data["data"])
         );
         this.userService.setSelectedUserFlag(true);
     }
 });
}
```

User Section Component

```js
unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

constructer(private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.userService.getSelectedUserFlag().pipe(filter((value) => {
    return value !== undefined || value !== false;
  }),
takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe(
    resp  => {
      console.log('user sec', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'))); 
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

Edit

```js
 this.userService.getSelectedUserFlag().pipe(
            first((user) => user !== null || user !== false || user !== undefined)
        ).subscribe(
            resp  => {
              console.log('user sec', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'))); 
            }
          );
```

Comment: I tried above logic. After login, in console `user sec` gets prints 3 times. first it has value `null` then other 2 times data seen on `user sec`. Not getting why its taking null first time.

Comment: Actually, in user section, I need to access that localstorage value on condition and need to access its attributes like I added in Edit of my question. I tried ` this.userService.getSelectedUserFlag().subscribe(
    resp  => {
      console.log('user sec', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selecteduser'))); console.log('selecteduser',this.selecteduser.first_name);
    }
  );` this in method of user section. but as it gives first null, so showing error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'first_name')`

Comment: @Ganesh, I updated the answer to filter out null values. You shouldn't get the above error, try again with code I edited.

Comment: do we need to clear/destroy `selectedUserInLocal$` ? as if I login for first time it prints only data of user. then if i logout and login again then I gets first null then 2 times user data. If I repeat this process null and data gets incremented. Pls check added screenshots in question.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to clear/destroy `selectedUserInLocal$` either when you leave the component or when you log out. I edited the code above to add  `takeUntil` as well as add  `unsubcribe$` subject to complete the Subject in `ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: @Ganesh, let me know if it works

Comment: somehow it still prints null and data twice. I am not getting why. My flow is like, in header component we stored data in localstorage and used that in components which I am redirecting after login. after login I am just navigating to timeline component which has user section component included

Comment: I am not getting why it is taking first null and then printing data twice.

Comment: Because the subscription never gets canceled or destroyed. when you come to the timeline component again, it subscribes again and shows the data twice. Did you try the above-edited code?

Comment: yes yes, I tried `takeUntil` and `ngOnDestroy()`. With this also getting same result as in the Edit 2 of question. That's why now I am not getting the reason.

Comment: @Ganesh, try the code in the new edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242148/discussion-between-ganesh-and-hassanmoin).